# How to get MonoDevelop to compile F# projects?

Tags: f#, monodevelop

The problem seems to be as follows, there compiler puts in a redundant reference to an assembly. I have no idea how to avoid this, there doesn't seem to be any field in MonoDevelop build options where this would be coming from:

```
Building: FSharpPractice (Debug|x86)

Building Solution FSharpPractice

Building: FSharpPractice (Debug|x86)

Performing main compilation...

C:\Program Files\FSharp-2.0.0.0\bin\fsc.exe --noframework --nologo
--target:exe
--out:"C:\Users\Alex Limonov\Documents\Projects\FSharpPractice\bin\Debug\FSharpPractice.exe"
--noframework
--debug-
--optimize-
--tailcalls-
-r:C:\Program Files\FSharp-2.0.0.0\bin\FSharp.Core.dll
-r:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll
-r:"C:\Program Files\FSharp-2.0.0.0\bin\FSharp.Core.dll"
-r:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll"
C:\Users\Alex Limonov\Documents\Projects\FSharpPractice\Program.fs

Build complete -- 2 errors, 0 warnings
```

Comment: Could you please post the 2 errors as well?

Answer (score 0):

In my case (MonoDevelop 2.4.2 with F# binding 2.4 on Mac OS X 10.6) I managed to compile F# project once I've explicitly added a reference to FSharp.Core.dll (4.0.0.0 here).